# Function accessing itself when name is overwritten by argument

Tags: javascript

Normally, a function can access itself like this:

```
(function f() {
    console.log(f); // Prints the function definition
}());
```

However, when the function `f` has an argument also called `f`, the argument takes precedence:

```
(function f(f) {
    console.log(f); // Prints 1
}(1));
```

In the second example, how can I access the function when one of the arguments has the same name as the function?

[Also, where can I find the documentation saying that the argument should take precedence over the function name?]

Comment: @DaveNewton: Could you please expand?

Comment: Just don't use the same name for the function and the argument... its an horrible idea

Comment: The parameter is the last thing called `f` in the function's scope, so the parameter wins. What's your purpose in this line of questioning? If we knew that we might be able to be more helpful--the naive answer is obvious; don't name a parameter the same as the function.

Comment: also, you don't have to name the parameter. you can get its value using arguments object

Comment: @DaveNewton: I'm working on [this quizz](http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/). Question 5 got me thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. Just follow this simple rule

> Don't shadow (or redeclare in a more specific scope) any variable that you want to use.

Note: `arguments.callee` will work for this, but only in some implentations.  And it's actually being phased *out* and is likely to disappear completely in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> [Also, where can I find the documentation saying that the argument
>   should take precedence over the function name?]

JavaScript is [lexically/statically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping). The following code contains two identifiers:

```
(function f(f) {
    console.log(f); // Prints 1
}(1));
```

- A function named `f` in the global scope (accessible using `window.f`)
- A parameter to the global function named `f` that is itself named `f`. This parameter is scoped to the function, which is a more-specific scope than the outer scope. In other words, it doesn't take any special rule for the parameter to take precedence; a local/inner/more-specific scope *always* shadows outer/less-specific scopes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use arguments.callee inside the function without using its name.

```
( function f( f ) {
    console.log( f ); // Prints 1
    console.log( arguments.callee ); // Prints the function definition
}( 1 ) );
```

Comment: In strict mode `arguments.callee` is forbidden according to the ECMAScript 5th edition. In other words, give your functions more expressive names.

Comment: @j-joey: How would you go about it in strict mode?

Comment: @Randomblue: Just provide a better name for the function.

Comment: It also prevents some optimization done by V8 (and possibly others)

Comment: @Russell i agree. but if i'm not on a serious project which i just do simple things where i name functions as f, something like that, i don't use strict mode. otherwise i always use self-explanatory names then i compress the code.

Comment: @Randomblue i always use expressive names. if you really have to use simple names, at least, you can use some prefixes, such as fn_: e.g function fn_f( f )